# Hibernate ManyToOne and OneToMany

Tags: hibernate, behavior

I have this relationship mapped for example.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shop")
public class Shop implements Serializable {

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "shop", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Event> events;

    ...

}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event")
public class Event implements Serializable {

    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "shop_id", nullable = false)
    private Shop shop;

    ...

}
```

When Local getEvent() is called is loaded in Colletion one list with a few Events, but each Event have inside another Shop might have inside another Event and successively.. Is that ok?. Can do any problem responsing JSON structure?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking.  If it's about whether defining both sides of the relationship will cause issues with things like circular/infinite dependencies, then no, no worries there.  Serializing your objects to JSON should not be a problem either, though of course you will need to write the serialization code yourself.

Comment: I use MappingJackson2JsonView to do, any problem?

Comment: @Dani Are you looking forward to know  whether there is any performance issue in using it..??

Comment: Yes, that's the question @Dileep.

Answer (score 2):

I had problem during serialization to JSON

```
...
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:72)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:23)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112) 
...
```

To solve it I used @JsonIgnore annotation in one property:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shop")
public class Shop implements Serializable {

    ...

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "shop", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Event> events;

    ...

 }
```

I hope this information is helpful. I can't add comments yet.

Comment: Thanks @paulek, Is perfect to me, I have only one question, I need no serialize this field, but, i need it on unserialize. Then I think that I must to put JsonIgnore in getter but no in setter, sure?

Comment: @Dani Exactly as you said.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate **checks the data with the identity of the data fetched** and is stored in a single object. By this hibernate identifies data to be fetched, and it fetch only the required data. Thus the load will be minimum.

But When you are in no need of any other details, its better to fetch data without using this Entity class with relations in it. Because it just buys too much of data. You can use this as a good choice

For eg
If you just need the name of an employee from a Table Employee for the Id in the Payment Table, then you can Use VO Class and select only the values that you need.

Follow the steps

1. Create a new Class(not an entity class mapped to a table)
2. Declare variables for each column you need to fetch with the same type as type of the column and create getters and setters.
3. Create a constructor with fields as arguments in the same Order as you want to fetch Query.
4. Execute The Query( can also use **inner Join**)

   select A.Col1, A.Col2,A.Col3,B.Col1,B.Col2 from Table1 A, Table2 B where A.RelationId=B.ID;

   **`A.RelationId=B.ID`** is the relation between the two tables.

You will be getting an object of the class voClassName with values that you need.

See [**section 21.1 of "Improving Performance"**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html) in the reference manual for more details in incresing performance using Relations and mapping.